# how to join 4 tables together in sql

Tags: sql

I have customers, products, orders orderdetails 4 table.
their relationship looks like this.[relashions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtkwI.png)

my SQL code looks like this:

```
select customers.CUSTOMERNAME, customers.STATE, customers.creditlimit
from customers
INNER JOIN ORDERS ON customers.customernumber = ORDERS.CUSTOMERNUMBER;

select ORDERDETAILS.PRICEEACH, ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITYORDERED
from ORDERDETAILS
inner join orders on ORDERS.ORDERNUMBER = ORDERDETAILS.ordernumber;

select products.productname
from products
inner join orderdetails on orderdetails.productcode = products.productcode;
```

I want to join the 4 tables into one table with selected segment. how can I do that?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of your database system (which you haven't told us) concerning doing JOINs? What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you already figured out your answer. Add all 3 queries together to make one. Please be mindful about joins and sequence of joins.

```
SELECT
    customers.CUSTOMERNAME, customers.STATE, customers.creditlimit ,
    ORDERDETAILS.PRICEEACH, ORDERDETAILS.QUANTITYORDERED ,
    products.productname
FROM ORDERS 
INNER JOIN customers ON customers.customernumber = ORDERS.CUSTOMERNUMBER
inner join orderdetails on ORDERS.ORDERNUMBER = ORDERDETAILS.ordernumber
inner join products on products.productcode=orderdetails.productcode
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "ORDERDETAILS"."ORDERNUMBER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: idk if you can see the relation picture, there is no relationship bet those tables, like customer and products,or orderdetails with customers etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
SELECT c.CUSTOMERNAME
    , o.CUSTOMERNUMBER
    , od.PRICEEACH
    , p.productname
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o
    on c.customernumber = o.customernumber
INNER JOIN ORDERDETAILS od
    on o.ORDERNUMBER = od.ORDERNUMBER
INNER JOIN products p
    on od.productcode = p.productcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to join 4 tables together--

```
SELECT CUST.CUSTOMERNAME
    ,CUST.STATE
    ,CUST.CREDITLIMIT 
    ,DET.PRICEEACH,
    ,DET.QUANTITYORDERED 
    ,PRD.PRODUCTNAME
FROM CUSTOMERS CUST
JOIN ORDERS ORD 
    ON CUST.CUSTOMERNUMBER = ORD.CUSTOMERNUMBER
JOIN ORDERDETAILS DET 
    ON ORD.ORDERNUMBER = DET.ORDERNUMBER
JOIN PRODUCTS PRD 
    ON DET.PRODUCTCODE = PRD.PRODUCTCODE;
```